# Format KML files in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, kml

I am using some KML files in an Android project and they are really, really poorly formatted so I wanted to use the format method, ctrl+shift+F but this did nothing. I tried adding the *.kml extension to to XML in Content Types under Preferences->General->Content Types and under Preferences->XML->XML Catalog I added two User Specified Entries corresponding to the schemaLocations in the kml file.

```
Entry element:      URI
Location:           /home/tstewart/Development/eclipse/kml22gx.xsd
URI:                file:/home/tstewart/Development/eclipse/kml22gx.xsd
Key type:           Namespace name
Key:                http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2
```

and

```
Entry element:      URI
Location:           /home/tstewart/Development/eclipse/ogckml22.xsd
URI:                file:/home/tstewart/Development/eclipse/ogckml22.xsd
Key type:           Namespace name
Key:                http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2
```

and the header info in the kml file was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2 http://code.google.com/apis/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd">
```

I have never really done this before so I am not sure what I am missing and the few answers I have seen about this did not seem to help.

Comment: Are you sure you're opening them in the right editor?

Comment: Sigh, it really was that simple, they were being opened by the text editor by default.

Comment: I've just added the content type under text / xml ".kml" and it worked (Eclipse Mars)